# how to make vpn shareable via hotspot for windows?

Tags: vpn, hotspot

I have a question about how to make VPN shareable via hotspot windows. I want to share\cast\hotspot\make my laptop a wifi router and share the VPN (I mean making all sites open like running psiphon & hotspot shield) so I could connect my devices to the internet without running a VPN app on them which will make my connection slower.

Also PS4 doesn't have a VPN app and my college network blocks everything, even youtube.

Comment: Welcome. Questions about specific OS or program configurations are better asked at SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

You may create WiFi access point via third party applications, alike [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/hotspot/):

> With Connectify Hotspot, you can transform your PC into a real WiFi hotspot, and share your computer’s Internet connection as Wi-Fi with any other PC or mobile device.

For example, together with [Witopia VPN](https://my.witopia.net/index.php?a=services) it will support [tethering/sharing of VPN connection](http://toomanyadapters.com/share-your-vpn-connection-connectify/), configured on your laptop:

1. Right click on the **Witopia** icon from your *System Tray* (the area by the clock). Choose *Gateways*, and then choose a gateway you would like to use.
2. Wait for the VPN to complete the connection. When it does, you will notice that the Witopia icon turns from white to blue. You can also check the location by double-clicking the Witopia icon in the System Tray.
3. Start **Connectify**. Configure a hotspot name and password if you haven’t already.
4. Click the “*Internet to Share*” pull down menu. Choose “*Viscosity Virtual Adapter V9.1*”
5. Click the “*Share Over*” pull down menu. Choose “*Wi-Fi*”.

Comment: @DavidPostill, thank you for the improvement. Feel free to up-vote if it's enough details provided from now. Totally re-edited my answer.